# How to store MySQL query results in another Table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to store results from following query into another table, considering there is an appropriate table already created?

```
SELECT labels.label,shortabstracts.ShortAbstract,images.LinkToImage,types.Type
FROM ner.images,ner.labels,ner.shortabstracts,ner.types
WHERE
  labels.Resource=images.Resource
  AND labels.Resource=shortabstracts.Resource
  AND labels.Resource=types.Resource;
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use the `INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT`....syntax:

```
INSERT INTO new_table_name
SELECT labels.label,shortabstracts.ShortAbstract,images.LinkToImage,types.Type 
FROM ner.images,ner.labels,ner.shortabstracts,ner.types 
WHERE labels.Resource=images.Resource AND labels.Resource=shortabstracts.Resource 
AND labels.Resource=types.Resource;
```

Answer (score 126):

If the table doesn't exist (and you e.g. don't want to create it because it may have lots of column names) you can create it on the fly...

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE another_table SELECT /* your query goes here */
```

Comment: While OP did say the table was already created, this answer is perfect for those who don't want to separately create a new table to store the results. Saves a step.

Comment: Is there a way to create the table locally for later querying, but not create a table on the server?

Answer (score 18):

if your table dosen't exist then

```
CREATE TABLE new_table SELECT //write your query here
```

if your table exist then you can just insert query

```
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT //write your query here
```

For more check [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html)

Comment: column name should be same in both table

Comment: @SameerBahad yes column name should be same, if different then need to assign

Answer (score 8):

```
INSERT INTO another_table SELECT /*your query goes here*/
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite Studio, I noticed that "AS" keyword is needed:

Query:

CREATE TABLE another_table **AS** SELECT /* your query goes here */

Comment: misleading comment