# mysql - How to send a query back to a database when I button a submit button is clicked

Tags: php

I have a simple query such as

```
SELECT * FROM COLOUR WHERE ID = '1'
```

when someone clicks a submit button I would like the information that is displayed from this query to save to another table within a database, is this possible?

Comment: *"is this possible?"* - Yes it is and I am certain that you will find something in a Google search.

Comment: yes it is my friend!

Comment: okay I wasn't sure but thank you

Comment: Provide some details I would gladly help you

Comment: I'm not even sure where to start and google hasn't been much help

Comment: think I need to do it a bit like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698401/how-to-store-mysql-query-results-in-another-table

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, but it is perhaps the basis of the question which you are missing. You have tagged this question with the "PHP" Tag, leading me to believe that you are trying to submit the information gathered from a page into another table.

In PHP Forms ([read about them here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)), the submit buttons call to a php file on your server, and you can basically run whatever you want from there assuming you have access. If it is a flat query, you might consider running a:

```
SELECT * FROM COLOUR WHERE ID = '1'
INTO `TABLE_2`;
```