# How to store result from query into a temporary storage?

Tags: php, mysql

I have read this [How to store MySQL query results in another Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698401/how-to-store-mysql-query-results-in-another-table), it works but the problem is that the table shown on my html file . How can I store the query result from my date range picker into a temporary table like a shopping cart? I want to allow the user to pick data from the database with different dates and then add it into a new table which I will put into a pdf file for the user to have.This is my query:

```
 $query = "SELECT *
 FROM gsm2 WHERE setTime BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND 
 '".$_POST["to_date"]."'
```

EDIT : I tried answers from the link from above which is:

```
 $query = "CREATE TABLE Table_name Insert into Table_name
SELECT *
 FROM gsm2 WHERE setTime BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND 
 '".$_POST["to_date"]."'
```

but it says `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,` on my table that is shown on my html file. I just wanna store the data into a temporary table and still show it into my html table.

this is how i show the result

```
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      $output .='   
       <table class="table table-bordered">  
            <tr>  
                <th width ="25%">Temperature</th> 
                <th width="25%">Humidity</th>  
                <th width="25%">Rainfall</th>   
                 <th width ="25%">Date</th>  
            </tr> ';
```

EDIT: I have successfully solved my html table problem using 2 queries.

```
 $query1 = "INSERT INTO aw SELECT *
 FROM gsm2 WHERE setTime BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND 
'".$_POST["to_date"]."' ";  

  $query2 = "SELECT *FROM gsm2 WHERE setTime BETWEEN'".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND '".$_POST["to_date"]."'  ";  
  mysqli_query($connect, $query1);       
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query2);
```

Comment: Use Sessions! Most shopping carts use a session based solution. Try this class for a quick solution. https://github.com/delboy1978uk/session

Comment: Your code seems not enough  .. there is not an mysqli_num_rows() in your code  .

Comment: @delboy1978uk but I dont have users on my system.

Comment: @scaisEdge added the mysqli num rows sorry

Comment: that doesn't stop you using sessions

Comment: @delboy1978uk alright, I am sorry for I am new with PHP I will try sessions thank you!

Comment: no problem, good luck! If you don't have composer installed, just download the session project and require in the class manually

Comment: @delboy1978uk  okay. thank you very much I will definitely finish this one

Comment: @delboy1978uk what file will I require? is it the `SessionManager.php` file?

Comment: that's the one!

Comment: @delboy1978uk do I need to extract the zip file and put everything on it on my directory?

Comment: you only need that SessionManager file. The rest is only used when installing via composer, wher it places it in a vendor directory

Comment: @delboy1978uk alright sir, thank you very much!

Comment: @delboy1978uk I think I just hit a brick wall, I'm out of ideas sir, can you tell me how do I use your session manager? I'm out of options sir sorry.

Comment: what have you tried? the readme has pretty clear instructions (I thought). Can you paste some code?