# Losing information when using BeautifulSoup

Tags: css, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am following the guide of 'Automate the Boring Stuff with Python'
practicing a project called 'Project: “I’m Feeling Lucky” Google Search'

but the CSS selector returns nothing

```
import requests,sys,webbrowser,bs4,pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    address = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
else:
    address = pyperclip.paste()

res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=' + str(address))
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
linkElems = soup.select('.r a')
for i in range (5):
    webbrowser.open('http://google.com' + linkElems[i].get('href'))**
```

I already tested the same code in the IDLE shell

It seems that

```
linkElems = soup.select('.r')
```

returns nothing

and after I checked the value returned by beautiful soup

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
```

I found all `class='r'` and `class='rc'` is gone for no reason.
But they were there in the raw HTML file.

Please tell me why and how to avoid such problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get version of HTML where it's defined class `r`, it's necessary to set `User-Agent` in headers:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

address = 'linux'

headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'}

res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=' + str(address), headers=headers)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

linkElems = soup.select('.r a')

for a in linkElems:
    if a.text.strip() == '':
        continue
    print(a.text)
```

Prints:

```
Linux.orghttps://www.linux.org/
Puhverdatud
Tõlgi see leht
Linux – Vikipeediahttps://et.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux
Puhverdatud
Sarnased
Linux - Wikipediahttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! But i still don't know the reason

Comment: @Tritium Some sites return different HTML version based on `User-Agent`. google is one of them. But yeah, sometimes it's hard to find it out - and it changes unpredictably.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Google blocks your request is because default requests user-agent is [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814). [Check what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent) thus blocking your request and resulting in completely different HTML with different elements and selectors. But sometimes you *can* receive a different HTML, with different selectors when using `user-agent`.

Learn more about [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) and [HTTP request `headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header).

Pass `user-agent` into request `headers`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

requests.get('YOUR_URL', headers=headers)
```

Try to use `lxml` parser instead, [it's faster.](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

---

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Description-Linkpythonbs4#bs4_results.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "My query goes here"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
  link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
  print(link)

-----

'''
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/entering-queries.html
https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/
https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/explaining-mysql-queries/
https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/sql-tutorial-introduction
https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-sub-queries/
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1255/getting-io-and-time-statistics-for-sql-server-queries/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698401/how-to-store-mysql-query-results-in-another-table
https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/sql/relational-queries-in-sql/a/more-efficient-sql-with-query-planning-and-optimization
http://cidrdb.org/cidr2011/Papers/CIDR11_Paper7.pdf
https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you only need to extract the data you want from JSON string rather than figuring out how to extract, maintain or bypass blocks from Google.

Code to integrate:

```py
params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "My query goes here",
    "hl": "en",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results["organic_results"]:
  print(result['link'])

-------
'''
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/entering-queries.html
https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/
https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/explaining-mysql-queries/
https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/sql-tutorial-introduction
https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-sub-queries/
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1255/getting-io-and-time-statistics-for-sql-server-queries/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698401/how-to-store-mysql-query-results-in-another-table
https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/sql/relational-queries-in-sql/a/more-efficient-sql-with-query-planning-and-optimization
http://cidrdb.org/cidr2011/Papers/CIDR11_Paper7.pdf
https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.